# Why are sections not working in R markdown?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, markdown

I am running the below code:

````
---
title: 'Reproducible Analysis'
author: Me!
abstract: "This document reproduces the analyses in our paper."
date: \today
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{float}
output:
    prettydoc::html_pretty:
      theme: architect
      highlight: github
      toc: true
      toc_depth: 2
graphics: yes
urlcolor: blue
---


```{r setup, include=F}
require("knitr")  
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, comment = NA, message = FALSE,
                      fig.width = 4.5, fig.height = 4, fig.align = "center",fig.pos = 'H')

#Change to whatever your directory is

# opts_knit$set(root.dir = )
home = 1

if(home==1){
  path0 = "/Users/...[myname]"

  }



theme_tufte_revised <- function(base_size = 12, base_family = base_font_family_tufte(), ticks = TRUE) {

  ret <- theme_bw(base_family = base_family, base_size = base_size) + 
    theme(
          axis.line = element_line(color = 'black'),
          axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.3), 
          axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 0.8),
          legend.background = element_blank(), 
          legend.key = element_blank(), 
          legend.title = element_text(face="plain"),
          panel.background = element_blank(), 
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid = element_blank(),
          plot.background = element_blank(),
          strip.background = element_blank()
    )

  if (!ticks) {
    ret <- ret + theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
  }

  ret
} 
is.extrafont.installed <- function(){
  if(is.element("extrafont", installed.packages()[,1])){
    library(extrafont)
    # probably need something here to run font_import()
    return(T)
  }else{
    warning("Library extrafont installed; using system sans/serif libraries as fallback fonts. 
    To enable full font support, run: 
      install.packages('extrafont') 
      font_import()")
    return(F)
  }
}

base_font_family_tufte <- function(){
  if(is.extrafont.installed()){
    library(extrafont)
    tuftefont <- choose_font(c("LM Roman 10"), quiet = FALSE)  
  }else{
    tuftefont <- 'LM Roman 10'
  }
  return(tuftefont)
}


knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = normalizePath(path0))
```
```{r,include = FALSE}




packages <- c("tidyr", "ggplot2", "ggjoy", "dplyr", "gridExtra", "mvtnorm",'doParallel','matrixStats',
              'foreach','pryr','pscl','cowplot','gridExtra','ggplot2','data.table','extrafont','stargazer','lfe','summarytools','bayesm','kableExtra','summarytools','ggthemes','viridis','ggh4x','gsubfn','lme4')

for (p in packages) {
  if ((p %in% rownames(installed.packages())) == FALSE) {
    install.packages(p, dependencies = TRUE)
  }
  library(p, character.only = TRUE)
}
loadfonts()

home=1

```


#Section 1 

This is totally section 1.
````

The output I get has

1. No table of contents.
2. No sections only text with #'s in front.

Comment: A space is required between the header character and the text: `# Section 1` not `#Section 1`

Comment: @27ϕ9 this fixed it, thank you!